# How to find total size of all files under the ownership of a user?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm trying to find out the total size of all files owned by a given user.

I've tried this:

```
find $myfolder -user $myuser -type f -exec du -ch {} +
```

But this gives me an error:

> missing argument to exec

and I don't know how to fix it. Can somebody can help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to terminate the -exec. If you want the totals for each directory 
possibly `-type d` is required.

```
find $myfolder -user $myuser -type d -exec du -ch {} \;
```

Comment: `+` should work as well; it tells `find` to pass multiple arguments (up to some internal limit) thus reducing the number of subprocesses spawned.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
find $myfolder -user gisi -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -sh
```

where user `gisi` is my cat ;)

Note the option `-s` for *summarize*

Further note that I'm using `find ... -print0` which on the one hand separates filenames by `0` bytes, which are one of the few characters which are not allowed in filenames, and on the other hand `xargs -0` which uses the `0` byte as the delimiter. This makes sure that even *exotic* filenames won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

some version of find command does not like "+" for termination of find command
use "\;" instead of "+"